# What do the numbers next to YouTube subscription lists actually count?

Tags: youtube

Here's a screenshot of my YouTube subscriptions

[image]

I originally expected the numbers to the right would indicate the release of new videos, but not so. The numbers next to the channels generally do not sum to the number in the red box at the top, and also generally do not correspond to the release of new videos in any kind of consistent way.

So what do these numbers actually indicate?

Comment: I investigated a bit, and this was useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/answers/comments/3ehbvj/what_does_the_grey_number_next_to_each_of_my/

Comment: Another clue is the comment by Seth on https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130203182041AAiBMmA , where he states that “it is the recent activities because if you click on them and look at recent activities, it says the number”. That should be verifiable!

Answer (score 1):

I think is the number of videos released/published by the channels you subscribed. The number refers to the videos published in the last period of time (a week maybe, or a month, here I'm not so sure).

I verified this on my youtube channel, and it seems to be so. Because if you click there in the right panel appears those videos released by channels in the last period of time. And if you move elsewhere in the menu the number disappears, as if you already viewed them.

Comment: These are guesses, not an answer.

Comment: I verified this on my youtube channel, and it seems to be so. Because if you click there in the right panel appears those videos released by channels in the last period of time. And if you move elsewhere in the menu the number disappears, as if you already viewed them.

Comment: I have *disproved* this by examining my own subscriptions. And the numbers do *not* go down when I view things, at least not until a day or two later, where they often go down whether I watch things or not. Also they don't count or sum correctly if that is the intended meaning.

Comment: If you hover over the subscriptions, you should see the three dot menu, which will provide a drop down to sort by specific sections, one of which is [New Activity](http://i.imgur.com/e15omca.png). When you search by New Activity it sorts by the recent activity of that user. As for what that activity could be, I'm clueless, as you can [see here](http://i.imgur.com/ko82TzU.png), the data on the channel indicates 46 items, but there's only 5 videos.

Comment: It's also very unintuitive that clicking an item with such numbers doesn't even _show_ you this supposed new content; it just gives the channel. Not even its "uploaded videos" tab, just the main channel view.

Comment: @spraff I had a similar problem, however the numbers decreased after force reloading the page. I have no idea what the numbers mean, but they disappear after viewing the channel and reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

it indicates the users activity in the past 24hrs (likes, subs, etc)

Comment: This is actually partially correct, from what I was told. As it supposedly is the number of actions that channel has done in a certain time, that you told YT to notify you of in the settings. As I cannot verify this, and it is a very silly and useless metric in any case, I did not write this an an answer. I upvoted this answer though, as it is the one closer to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's actually the number of uploads posted within the current week that you are viewing the subscriptions bar in.